# 2 form's side by side float

Tags: html, css

So i have 2 forms, register and login on the same page. Now i'm styling my forms/layout and want that both form are nice side-by-side.

From now on i'm using this:

HTML:

```
<div class="links">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <?php include ("register.php");?>
</div>

<div class="rechts">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <?php include ("login.php");?>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.links{
    float: left;
    width:50%
}
.rechts{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This works, BUT i want that the right form is sticky to the right side. As you can see in my image it has lots of space right. when i put text-align: right; there, my text only sticks to the form. but the form doesn't want to get aside.

Image:
[image: Picture about my problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply set a specific width for your right hand form, like so:

```
.rechts{
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CcZXk/

Alternatively, it may work correctly if you completely remove the `width:50%;` on the right hand div. This would depend on the content of that div, however. (Floated elements work a bit like inline elements in that they try to be as small as possible, while still containing all of their content. In other words, if you have a long line of text or a long image or input field inside the div, removing `width:50%;` would not work, as the div will be too wide and wrap onto the next line.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is working correct, because it has **50% of width**.

change it pixels/auto

```
.links{
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
.rechts{
    width: auto;
    float: right;
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7VbL/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.rechts{
width:auto;
margin-right:0;
float:right;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

**OR.....**

```
<div class="rechts">
  <div class="inner">
     <h2>Login</h2>
     <?php include ("login.php");?>
  </div>
</div>

.rechts{
float: right;
width: 50%;
}
.inner{
float: right;
width:auto;
margin-right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `float` directive you can also use `display`. You can easily add *media queries* to your stylesheet and change it back to `display: block` in order to avoid horizontal scrolling on smaller screen sizes.

See http://jsfiddle.net/QnDte/

```
/* CSS */
 .register, 
.login {
    display: table-cell;
}
.register_and_login {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="register_and_login">
    <div class="register">
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <?php include ( "register.php");?>
    </div>
    <div class="login">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <?php include ( "login.php");?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="mainblock">
<div class="links">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <?php include ("register.php");?>
</div>

<div class="rechts">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <?php include ("login.php");?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.mylinks{
    float: left;
    width:50%;
}
.rechts{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
} 
.mainblock
{
    width: 1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```